# Laravel Voyager View [formfields.range] not found

Tags: laravel, voyager

i already make a laravel voyager custom formfields as RangeFormFields in App\FormFields with code like this..

```
    <?php

namespace App\FormFields;

use TCG\Voyager\FormFields\AbstractHandler;

class RangeFormField extends AbstractHandler
{
    protected $codename = 'range';

    public function createContent($row, $dataType, $dataTypeContent, $options)
    {
        return view('formfields.range', [
            'row' => $row,
            'options' => $options,
            'dataType' => $dataType,
            'dataTypeContent' => $dataTypeContent
        ]);
    }
}
```

range.blade.php in tcg\voyager\resources\views\formfields like this

```
<input type="range"
   class="form-control"
   name="{{ $row->field }}"
   type="number"
   @if($row->required == 1) required @endif
   @if(isset($options->min)) min="{{ $options->min }}" @endif
   @if(isset($options->max)) max="{{ $options->max }}" @endif
   step="{{ $options->step ?? 'any' }}"
   placeholder="{{ old($row->field, $options->placeholder ?? $row->getTranslatedAttribute('display_name')) }}"
   value="{{ old($row->field, $dataTypeContent->{$row->field} ?? $options->default ?? '') }}">
```

and this in AppServiceProviders

```
    <?php

namespace App\Providers;

    use TCG\Voyager\Facades\Voyager;
    use App\FormFields\RangeFormField;
    use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public function register()
    {
        Voyager::`addFormField(RangeFormField`::class);
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

but still have error.
how do i make it work like https://voyager-docs.devdojo.com/customization/adding-custom-formfields
should i just change something or should i make range.blade.php somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `formfields.range` to `voyager::formfields.range` in ***RangeFormFields.php*** file

like that :

```
    <?php

namespace App\FormFields;

use TCG\Voyager\FormFields\AbstractHandler;

class RangeFormField extends AbstractHandler
{
    protected $codename = 'range';

    public function createContent($row, $dataType, $dataTypeContent, $options)
    {
        return view('voyager::formfields.range', [
            'row' => $row,
            'options' => $options,
            'dataType' => $dataType,
            'dataTypeContent' => $dataTypeContent
        ]);
    }
}
```